# Read a flat file in Pentaho Spoon and then export it's metadata into a CSV

Tags: csv, metadata, pentaho, flat-file, pentaho-spoon

I am wondering if it is possible to extract the metadata of a flat file in a CSV using Pentaho Spoon. What I mean by that is for example get a CSV file input step, choose the file you want to read and then somehow get access to the metadata of that file and export it into a CSV.

I found on the documentation a step called Metadata Structured that was introduced in 3.1.0 but I can't find it in the latest version of Spoon, maybe it got removed by now.

Update: I found the "Metadata structure of stream" that almost does what I need to be done. Right now my transformation looks like this: csv file input -> metadata structure of stream -> text file ouput. The problem is that it doesnt extract all the metadata. It doesn't extract Format, Decimal and Group. It also gets me an Origin column that I don't really need and I have to get rid of it.

Update2: I keep trying to get to those columns that are missing but the problem is that the Metadata structure of stream step only outputs these columns "Position,Fieldname,Comments,Type,Length,Precision,Origin" so I cannot really access the format column for example that is an input for the step :( I can't really find a work-around for this

Comment: The metadata structure of the stream is determined by what the CSV file input step says it is. That in turn is configured by you in the step's various tabs. Unfortunately, there is no step that replicates the "Get fields" button in the CSV file input step's configuration.